# Want to use Latest version of SonarQube(6.2) with java 6. Any Idea?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I want to use SonarQube to check code quality, afaik  sonarQube 6.2 works with java 8, But my production environment have java 6 installed. so every ti,e when i start SONAR.bat to start the server its give jvm java class error.

ANY Suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to install a second JRE, and use it with SonarQube. Look at `$SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf`. Just above the line:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS
```

You find:

```
#wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java

wrapper.java.command=java
```

Comment-out the second line, uncomment the first one, and make it point to your Java 8 installation.

Comment: And what happens when you correct the log file perms?

Comment: Finally its works, the only problem after @G.Ann suggestion  is with permissions of java 8. once give it permission (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2623670/-access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-folders-in-windows) its work fine Thanks !! G.Ann